# Python 3.6 - Splitting hex data

Tags: python-3.x, split, binary, hex

I am trying to read a binary file and get out a header which is in utf-8 format. However the rest of the file has byte values that go over decimal 127, so I cannot convert that to a string. I have to split the text until ; (or 0x3B) and I cannot get it to work.

```
with open("test_qifs_single_frame.qifs", "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()

print(binascii.hexlify(data))
```

I cannot read it in as a string either, because it tells me that I cannot decode 0x81 to UTF-8. Which I understand, it falls outside of the ASCII range. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file byte by byte until you reach the stop character, then decode the data that you have read.

**Create some sample data**

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> header = 'Heaðer;'.encode('utf-8')
>>> bs = b''.join(bytes.fromhex('{:0>2x}'.format(randint(0, 255))) for _ in range(56))
>>> with open('test_qifs_single_frame.qifs', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(header + bs)
>>>
```

**Read the header from the file**

```
>>> # Create a bytearray to hold the bytes that we read.
>>> ba = bytearray()

>>> import functools
>>> with open('test_qifs_single_frame.qifs', 'rb') as f:
...     breader = functools.partial(f.read, 1)
...     for b in iter(breader, b';'):
...         ba += b
... 
>>> ba
bytearray(b'Hea\xc3\xb0er')
>>> ba.decode('utf-8')
'Heaðer'
```

If the [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) builtin is passed a *callable* and a value, it will call the callable until it returns the value.  In the code we use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a function that reads the file one byte at a time, then pass this to `iter`.